# Maven не генерируется с консоли

Tags: java, maven

Хочу сгенерировать maven проект с архитипа через консоль.
На официальном сайте взял команду `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-simple -DarchetypeVersion=1.4`, но при запуске в пустой папке выдает ошибку

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.072 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-01T15:04:06+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\user\Desktop\test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это Windows - может помочь поставить кавычки:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-simple" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4"
```